# How to solve Linear Algebra equation Az=b where z is non-positive? [PYTHON]

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-algebra

Hi I want to solve a Linear Algebra equation `Az = B` where the ***output matrix variables are*** ***non-positive***.

*example.*

```
A = np.array([[1,2]
              [3,4]]

b = np.array([1,2])

z = [x,y]
```

solving using `z = np.linalg.solve(A,b)` gives me both positive and negative variables for `x` and `y`.I want the variables to be `-x` and `-y`. How do I do this? Thank you so much!

Comment: What if the solution happens to be positive? Try `http://www.wolframalpha.com/` for your math, so you have a test case.  `Solve [{{1,2},{3,4}}.{x,y} = {1,2},{x,y}]`

Comment: I wrote the example completely randomly and it seems that the answer is x = 0 and y =1/2. However, is it possible to solve the equation so that x and y are both negative?

Comment: Not this particular equation as given, but if you change the numbers, yes, of course. But that's a Math question, not one for Python.

Comment: Then is it possible to express ratios into a matrix? For example Lets say I have x/y = 1/2. If I write that equation into a matrix form would [1 -0.5] = [0] be correct?

Comment: If `2 x= 1 y` you have only one equation `2x - y = 0`. If you write out your existing matrix equation as individual equations they read `1x+2y= 1` and `3x+4y= 2`. You can put any coefficients you want. Look up systems of linear equations for the general theory. The preferred way to solve this systems is with determinants. But all this is math, not Python so it properly belongs on MathOverflow.